# "without" verb adverb position

Tags: grammar, adverbs

How do we say this correctly:
"you can't do that without doing this first" 
OR
"you can't do that without first doing this"?

Similary

"I want you to do always your homework timely"
"I want you to always do your homework timely"
"I want you to do your homework always timely"
"I want you to do your homework timely always"

Is there a rule of thumb or every case is unique?

Comment: timely has to be: do your work in a timely *manner*.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs of indefinite frequency such as "always" go before a main verb, between an auxiliary verb and main verb, and after the verb *to be*. However, there are always exceptions to the general rules regarding the position of adverbs, depending on what the speaker is emphasising.

Comment: Thank you, what about this part of the question? "How do we say this correctly: "you can't do that without doing this first" OR "you can't do that without first doing this"?"